# Opening winmail.dat attachments

Tags: file-format

After saving an attachment in a Thunderbird mail message to my Ubuntu 16.04 files, I was informed that a winmail.dat file can't be opened. I am not tech-savvy. Is there an easy solution?

Comment: I would query your system what type of file it is, ie. `file /path/winmail.dat` which should tell you what type of file it is (*not from it's name, but the file's contents*; sorry it's a command as it's where I'd do it)

Comment: Have you looked at this tool? https://www.winmaildat.com/

Comment: I am not at all familiar with how the terminal works. I don't know how to query the system about the file. I tried "file /path/winmail.dat" and got  "no such file or directory". I also tried Graham's suggestion of https://www.winmaildat.com/ and got the file there as a "docx", but was still unable to open it. I am apparently misunderstanding the directions and options I am given.  I appreciate your taking time for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Thunderbird 91.1.7, and when I load Lookout from the website
https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/lookout-fix-version/
I get a complaint about the file being corrupt.
However, when I download the addon-file from within Thunderbird, quit and restart Thunderbird, I am able to look at the winmail.dat file successfully.
Because I am in Canada, Thunderbird downloads from
https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-CA/thunderbird/search/?q=Lookout

Comment: Hello. You are just repeating what the question asks.

Comment: I am no longer using Ubuntu 16.04. Lookout (fix version) installed from Thunderbird addons in Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft Outlook can include attachments in email using a proprietary format. Email clients that do not support the Outlook format see that attachment as a file `winmail.dat`. You can still decode the attachment using a command line tool `tnef`.

Install the command line tool with the command

```
sudo apt install tnef
```

Then you can easily decode the `winmail.dat` file into the original binary files with

```
tnef winmail.dat
```

Following is in case you are very unfamiliar with how the terminal works.

If you are not used to working with the terminal: the command above assumes that your current working directory (folder) is containing `winmail.dat`. You can easily open a terminal in the folder where your winmail.dat folder resides using the file manager.

Alternatively, you can open a terminal. By default, the current folder will be your home folder (`/home/<yourlogin>` which can be indicated as `~`). You can check in which folder you are with the `pwd` command. You can check what files are present in the current folder with the `ls` command. Otherwise, you need to first change to the directory where the file resides. There, you use the `cd` command. Suppose you downloaded the attachment in your "Downloads" folder, then you can in the terminal move to that directory with the command:

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

after which you will successfully be able to execute the command to decode the attachment.

Comment: I am not at all familiar with how the terminal works. I seem to have installed the tnef tool with the command, but have not succeeded in following the directions on how to use it. When I entered "pwd" in the terminal I got nothing; the same with "1s". I tried "tnef winmail.dat" in several places without result. Using the"cd" command got "no such file or directory". I am obviously out of my depth here. I appreciate your taking time for me.

Comment: You need to spend an hour to read somewhere about the basics of the linux terminal. `pwd` always returns the current folder. `ls` stands for "list" and provides the names of the files and folders in the current directory. `cd` stands for "change directory. You can easily open a terminal in the current folder with the file manager. Then, all that is left is the tnef command. Added some of that info.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I started a search for terminal basics. It will take me some time to follow up with  the search results, so I can't say the problem has been solved.

Comment: I think this solves the problem. Whether it is an easy solution, however, is a matter of taste. Some would consider 1) opening the terminal 2) issuing two commands, i.e. "cd ~/Downloads" and then "tnef winmail.dat" not to be difficult indeed, but that is a matter of appreciation. One could add this as a right-click option in the file manager to make even more easy, but that is another question.

Comment: I'm still struggling to follow the directions. I keep getting "no such file or directory exists", no matter what filename or folder I paste in. I guess I need to do some studying. Thank you.

Comment: In the directory where I saved the `winmail.dat`, I first created a subdirectory with `mkdir attachment` and then did `tnef -f winmail.dat -C \`pwd\`/attachment --unix-paths` to extract it within `<current_working_directory>/attachment` and "Make Windows filenames more Unix friendly". This way it worked for me. More options with `tnef --help`.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using Thunderbird as your e-mail client, there is a handy add-on called LookOut, which automatically decodes those attachments via TNEF.
https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/lookout/

Comment: I tried the add-on suggested by vertereponse and got: "This add-on cannot be installed because it appears to be corrupt."

Comment: There is a newer version called "LookOut (fix version)" at https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/lookout-fix-version/ which works as of 12 October 2021 and Thunderbird version 91.1.0.